# Using GenericTabularInline in the Django Admin to find existing collections

Tags: python, django

In the Django admin I can show inline the reverse of the Generic relationship by using [GenericTabularInline](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#generic-relations-in-admin). This works....

```
  class Art(TimeDateStampedModel):
      collections = GenericRelation('apps.Collection')
```

*admin.py*

```
class CollectionsInline(GenericTabularInline):
    model = Collection

class ArtAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [
        CollectionsInline,
        MediaActivityInline,
    ]
```

But it only lets me add new collections or update ones already related. **How can a search/select or pick an existing `Collection` from `Art`.**

I have tried using the `GenericRelation` on Art this but it does not work:

```
class ArtAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fieldsets = (
        ('', {
            'fields': ('collections'),
        }),

    )
```

Comment: I don't think it will be straight forward to do this in the Django admin. I'm not sure it makes sense either. It looks like `Collection` has a generic foreign key, so each collection is linked to one external model. If you can select collections from the `Art` admin, then you would be 'stealing' the collection from another object, which might be confusing.

Comment: @Alasdair I guess that this would also orphan the collection and give errors?

Comment: may I need a many-to-many generic relationship, it that exists.

Comment: I don't think it would orphan it, it would reassign it to a different object. If `collection` was assigned to `art1`, but you 'selected' it in the admin for `art2`, then it would be reassigned to `art2`, and wouldn't belong to `art1` any more.

Comment: Yes, it sounds like your current generic foreign key isn't quite what you want. You could try creating a model e.g. `CollectionMember` (not a great name) with a foreign key to collection, and a generic foreign key. Add the `CollectionMember` as a generic inline in your admin, and you'll be able to select the collection.

Comment: @Alasdair Cool, well that solves a different issue. sorry for going off topic, but thanks! I'm happy with your answer in that it does not make sense. could you post an answer so other can benefit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You currently have a generic foreign key in your `Collection` model. It sounds like this isn't what you want, because you want to be able to assign each `collection` to more than one external object.

You could try creating a model e.g. `CollectionMember` (not a great name), with a foreign key to collection, and a generic foreign key.

```
class CollectionMember(models.Model):
    """
    Allows collections to be assigned to multiple external 
    objects using a generic foreign key
    """
    collection = models.ForeignKey(Collection)
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
```

Add the CollectionMember as a generic inline in your `ArtAdmin`, then you'll be able to choose the collection for each `collection_member` inline.